# Getting shareable link to document in react app

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, pdf.js

I am currently making an app that generates Itineraries and I am able to convert the html to pdf using `PDFjs` using something like this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML(html);
doc.save("YourItinerary.pdf");
```

How should I proceed about making a shareable link to this pdf on client-side preferably using an API such as `Google Drive`?

Comment: You can't really have a shareable link on the client side without having logic to support it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the shareable link would be to get the `webViewLink` which you can try by passing `webViewLink` as parameter in the 'fields' property in [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get). This returns a link you can open in any browser. However, you also have to deal with permissions.

To make the `webViewLink` (your shareable link) work for anyone you can use in [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create):

```
{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "anyone",
}
```

To make the `webViewLink` available to certain users only you'll have a request body like:

```
{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "someuser@gmail.com"
}
```